# How to save a file for which I have no write permissions on Windows

Tags: vim-windows, save

I would like to edit files like `C:\Widows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` that need administrative privilege to be modified.

How can save the file on Windows if Vim has not been starter with administrator privileges?

Comment: I wonder if you can use a PowerShell command to clobber the file with contents coming from stdin and then use the suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/q/7690994/9447571 to run it with elevated privileges, if so you could use `:w !…` to write the contents to that command and have it write to the file. (This would be akin to the `:w !sudo tee % >/dev/null` solution for Linux/Unix.)

Comment: Thanks. The suggestion mention elevated privilege but what is I need another account (user) ?

Answer (score 5):

Some time ago I wrote a small utility [xmove](https://github.com/matveyt/xmove).

Basically, it saves stdin into temporary file and re-runs itself with elevated privileges. Finally, the second instance moves temporary file to the proper destination.

So this is supposed to do the trick: `:w !xmove %` and then `set nomod`. You can pull, build and check if it still works.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look. But what is I need another account (user) to write the file?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt If you want to impersonate a user other than administrator you need to add that feature yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I have no access to my development environment this week. I'll add personalization when I come back. I'll keep you informed.

Answer (score 2):

I have created the [SudoEdit](https://github.com/chrisbra/SudoEdit.vim) vim plugin, that allows to elevate using several different methods (including [UAC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works)) and that should also work on Windows.

Comment: Hi @Christian, I have tried to use the solution on Windows but I face some problems. With the `SudoWrite` command I get the following error message:  `Line 118: EW37: No write since last change (add ! to override)` but adding `'!`' doesn't help. With the `SudoRead` command a copy of the file is created in `C:\Users\Public` but the code seems to try to access the folder `C:\Users\Public` instead of the file and fails.

Comment: can you please create an issue about this? I can then look into it

Comment: Hi @Christian I have created an issue and a Pull Request with my proposed changes. Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem entirely since to change `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` I need both another user and the elevated mode and it seems that runas provide only the first.

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward solution would be
to save the file to some other location (where you *do* have write access),
like `\temp` or `\Users\<your-user-name>\Documents`,
with the `:w <pathname>` command,
and then go to a Command Prompt or PowerShell
that’s running with elevated privileges (running as Administrator)
and copy your temporary file over the target. 
If you need to use the privileges of some other user
(other than Administrator),
use `runas` to start the Command Prompt or PowerShell.